# Filtro instável no início

Tags: c#, filter

Estou a ter um problema com os meus filtros [`IIR`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtro_IIR). Estou a tentar filtrar um sinal `ECG` (Electrogcardiograma) através dum filtro que passa baixo IIR, e depois por um que passa alto IIR. O problema é que este filtro está instável no início. E por causa de estar instável, adiciona um pico não existente logo no inicio, estabilizando depois.

Tentei usar o filtro inicializando os valores de saída `Y` com valor igual a `0` mas mesmo assim continua instável no começo. Acho que os valores de `B` e `A` estão correctos porque os estou a copiar dum programa em `python` que funciona correctamente.

Neste momento estou a trabalhar em `C#` (se bem que isso não será muito relevante x) )

Se alguém me souber indicar o porque desta instabilidade no início eu agradeceria.

Obrigado.

Comment: Então, fiz uma pequena edição na sua pergunta pra aumentar as chances de resposta. Dá uma olhada pra ver se ainda reflete o que vc precisa. PS: Ah, e juntar um trecho do código que está utilizando pode aumentar as chances obter respostas substancialmente.